# useEffect .map not a function React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot, react-hooks

Here's my issue: I am setting the state of currentUser, sometimes its undefined, sometimes its not (from the API). I then pass it to the second useEffect, I set the carrier state, and then as I try to fetch users from that carrier based on the ID, carrier.id appears to be undefined for some reason.

What am I doing wrong here?

I use this useEffect to watch for any changes to the currentUser that is logged in. I pass the user from Auth Service to currentUser state.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const user = AuthService.getCurrentUser();
  // console.log(user);

  if (user) {
    setCurrentUser(user);
    // console.log(currentUser);
  } else {
    console.log("user not logged");
  }
}, []);
```

I am trying to pass the ID from currentUser to the fetch endpoint for the useEffect below to receive the carrier the user is attached to/supervisor of.

```
// Fetches the carrier that the user is supervisor in 


const [carrier, setCarrier] = useState({

});

useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:8080/supervisor/${currentUser.id}/carriers`, {
        headers: new Headers({
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + currentUser.accessToken, 
          }), 
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => setCarrier(json))
}, [carrier])

const [employees, setEmployees] = useState([

])
```

I then pass the carrier.id to the endpoint to receive the users attached to the specific carrier that the user is in.

```
// fetches the users from the specific carrier

useEffect(() => {
  fetch(`http://localhost:8080/supervisor/carriers/${carrier.id}/employees/`, {
      headers: new Headers({
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + currentUser.accessToken, 
        }), 
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => setEmployees(json))
}, [employees])



 {employees.length > 0 && employees.map((employeeCarrier) => (   
      <Slide direction="up" in={employees} mountOnEnter unmountOnExit>
      <TableRow key={employeeCarrier.id}>
            <TableCell>{employeeCarrier.fullname}</TableCell>
            <TableCell>{employeeCarrier.email}</TableCell>
            <TableCell>{employeeCarrier.crn}</TableCell>
            <TableCell>{employeeCarrier.role}</TableCell>
            <TableCell>{employeeCarrier.address}</TableCell>
            <TableCell>{employeeCarrier.birthday}</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="center">
            <Tooltip title="Modify">
                        {/* <IconButton aria-label="modify" size="small" onClick={() => handleClickOpenEditUser(user)}> */}
                            <EditIcon />
                         {/* </IconButton> */}
                        </Tooltip> 
                      <Tooltip title="Delete">
                        {/* <IconButton aria-label="delete" onClick={()=>deleteUser(user.id)}> */}
                          <DeleteIcon />
                        {/* </IconButton> */}
                       </Tooltip> 
            </TableCell>
          </TableRow>
          </Slide>
        ))}
```

Comment: This code is confusing. It looks like the first `usEffect` will cause an infinite loop, because it does an API call that sets carrier in its callback, however carrier is a dependency of the effect so setting it will trigger the effect to run again. Secondly, your second `useEffect` has nothing to do with carrier, and given that carrier is initially an empty object when that effect runs on mount then yes, `carrier.id` will be undefined. Thirdly, the title of your question is about a map error but there's no map in your code

Comment: I've added the rest of the code, my apologies.

Comment: Since the second effect depends on the carrier's ID, I think you need to handle that being undefined and also add it as a dependency. So in the 2nd `useEffect` before you do that request, make sure the carrier ID is defined: `if (!!!carrier.id) return;` and then in the effect's dependency add the carrier: `[carrier, employees]`. That way it won't do the API request if carrier ID isn't defined, then when carrier is fetched and set in state it will do this request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand your question. Your hierarchy seems to be something like this:

1. See if the User is authenticated.
2. If authenticated, fetch the carriers for the users.
3. If carriers, fetch the employees for the carrier.

Okay, so first thing, as @Jayce444 mentioned, your useEffect() is problematic, because it monitors carrier, and also fetches carrier.

What you actually want is this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const user = AuthService.getCurrentUser();
  // console.log(user);

  if (user) {
    setCurrentUser(user);
    // console.log(currentUser);
  } else {
    console.log("user not logged");
  }
}, []);


useEffect(() => {
fetch(`http://localhost:8080/supervisor/${currentUser.id}/carriers`, {
        headers: new Headers({
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + currentUser.accessToken, 
          }), 
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => setCarrier(json))
}, [currentUser]); //Should be currentUser not carrier
```

Do you see why? When the currentUser *changes* only then do we want the carrier to be fetched.

Extending the same concept:

```
useEffect( () => {
  fetch(`http://localhost:8080/supervisor/carriers/${carrier.id}/employees/`, {
      headers: new Headers({
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + currentUser.accessToken, 
        }), 
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => setEmployees(json))
}, [carrier])
```

Only fetch new employees when *carrier* changes.

Does that make sense? UseEffect basically says: If this variable/dependancy changes, what should I do?

Comment: Cool. Happy to help.